# reloaded wpf window

Tags: c#, wpf, window

I have main wpf window, in this window I create new slave windows and add in dictionary. It is possible, after closing the slave window, it showed once again.

```
public class MainWindow:Window
{
private dictionary<string, SlaveWindow> _winDic= new dictionary<string, SlaveWindow>();

public void SomeMethod()
{

var mySlaveWindow = new SlaveWindow();
//add to dictionary
_winDic.Add("mySlaveWindow",w);

//close slave window w


//show
_winDic[mySlaveWindow].Show();
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This following way of doing this is taken from [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc656741%28VS.90%29.aspx) msdn page.

Subscribe to the Closing event for the Window and add this in code behind.

```
private bool m_close = false;
// Shadow Window.Close to make sure we bypass the Hide call in 
// the Closing event handler
public new void Close()
{
    m_close = true;
    base.Close();
}
private void Window_Closing(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
{
    // If Close() was called, close the window (instead of hiding it)
    if (m_close == true)
    {
        return;
    }
    // Hide the window (instead of closing it)
    e.Cancel = true;
    this.Hide();
}
```

This will make sure your Window finally closes and is not left hanging.

Comment: Some questions: 1) I don't see why only one of these uses Dispatcher.BeginInvoke - if the first needs it, doesn't the second example also need it? 2) shouldn't your second example be calling base.OnClosing, and 3) any advantage to using Visibility rather than Hide(), which is more descriptive of what's being done?

Comment: Good questions. I didn't make that code up myself but I believe that Dispatcher.BeginInvoke is used in order to avoid "InvalidOperationException - Visibility is set, or Show, ShowDialog, or Close is called while a window is closing" from here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.window.closing(v=VS.90).aspx.
Agreed, Hide() is more descriptive. I also updated my answer to what Microsoft recommends from this link. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc656741(VS.90).aspx

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to hide the window rather than closing it.

If you call `Hide()`, the window will vanish like it would when you call `Close()` but you'll be able to reshow it  later by calling `Show()` again.

Comment: Yeah - I interpreted the question a little too literally. I took the comment in the code saying "close slave window w" to mean that he was intending to close the window from code.